# How can i avoid to rewrite the same long expression with generic type in rust?

Tags: generics, matrix, rust

I'm writing a crate to manage Matrix and define multiple function on it to learn the language and solidify my knowledge in math. I use Matrix with const generic type Size and I have a little problem I often use the same expression in my code : Matrix<Row,Column> with
Row and Column const generic type.How can i shorten the expression ?
This is my begening of code :

```rust
#[derive(Debug,Clone)]
pub struct Matrix<const Row:usize,const Column:usize>{
  pub array:[[f64;Column];Row]
  
}


impl <const Row:usize,const Column:usize>Matrix<Row,Column>{
  pub const fn new()->Matrix<Row, Column> {
    Matrix {
      array: [[0.0; Column]; Row]
    }
  }
  
}

impl <const Row:usize,const Column:usize> std::ops::Index<usize> for Matrix<Row,Column>{
  type Output = [f64;Column];
  
  fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
    &self.array[index]
  }
}
impl <const Row:usize,const Column:usize> std::ops::IndexMut<usize> for Matrix<Row,Column>{
  fn index_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Self::Output {
    &mut self.array[index]
  }
}
```

I want something like #define MATRIX Matrix<Row,Column> in C.

Thank for the anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust doesn't have arbitrary text substitution, but it does have macros that you can use to achieve your goal of reducing repetition in your code.

```
macro_rules! matrix_impl {
    ( { $($body:tt)* } ) => {
        impl<const Row:usize, const Column:usize> Matrix<Row, Column> {
            $($body)*
        }
    };
    
    ( $tr:ty { $($body:tt)* } ) => {
        impl<const Row:usize, const Column:usize> $tr for Matrix<Row, Column> {
            $($body)*
        }
    };
}
```

This declares a macro that can be passed a block (`{}`) containing any valid Rust tokens, which will get "pasted" into an `impl` block.  If you include a leading type then the generated `impl` will be for that trait.

For example:

```
matrix_impl!({
  pub const fn new()->Matrix<Row, Column> {
    Matrix {
      array: [[0.0; Column]; Row]
    }
  }
});

matrix_impl!(std::ops::Index<usize> {
  type Output = [f64;Column];
  
  fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
    &self.array[index]
  }
});

matrix_impl!(std::ops::IndexMut<usize> {
  fn index_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Self::Output {
    &mut self.array[index]
  }
});
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=21bf5b175701fbc26d5e5e9bb40e4e1f))